# Reaction of coloured metal complexes with water and sulfuric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

**Reaction of coloured metal complexes with water and sulfuric acid**

I recently started researching the coloured compounds made from transition metals focusing on one with oxidation state II, so Mn,Fe,Co,Ni,Cu and Zn with all of them in hydrated metal sulfate complexes.

I've done some research and found why they have their colours. However I still do not know **what metal ligand complex will my compounds will make when reacted with water and concentrated sulfuric acid?**

Knowing the end product would help me in formulating the reaction equation and would be easy to understand for the presentation.

Comment: If your question is about the composition, synthesis and appearance for *all* compounds with $\ce{M(H2O)_$x$SO4}$ formula (M = Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn), then it seems to be very broad.

Comment: @andselisk I just chose this from a few experiments that were available and we aren't expected to go too deep. I need to explain why they have different colours, google helped with that and also show the reaction equations forming the coloured compound which i am  not a 100% sure about. For Fe(II) it would be green and the complex would be $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^2+}$ but I don't know what complex the others would make.

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear to me: your question states that you want to know what the reaction of metal complexes with conc sulfuric acid is, but comment says otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a metal is made to react with sulfuric acid, it will form a sulfate salt. When you dissolve those sulfates in water, you would be studying the color of the aquated metal ion. Sulfate is just a counter ion in each case. Search crystal field theory.

You are right, iron (II) sulfate in water would be light green, Zn would be colorless, Mn would be light pinkish, nickel would be green, copper would be blue. This is the color of aquated metal ion i.e. when the central metal ion is surrounded by six water molecules.

Comment: and would the general formula for each of these complexes be $\ce{M(H2O)^2+_$6$}$ where M = Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn? Crystal Field Theory would then explain why they have different colours?

Comment: Yes, you are right.